# LibreOffice Calc #name error

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Tell me, please, what's the problem. I'm trying to write an IF, but I'm constantly getting a #name error. Moreover, even with the simplest conditions, like 0 <1. The syntax was looked up in the documentation - `=IF(x<y;z;b)`.

[image: error1]

[image: error2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like Calc is expecting Russian function names (or Ukranian or whatever language that is).  For best interoperability, check *Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice Calc -> Formula -> Use English function names*.

Alternatively, to find out what name is expected, click the `fx` icon to open the Function Wizard.  Choose the name of the function from a list.

Comment: I suspect this is right.  If LO recognized the function, it would be capitalized.

Comment: Oh, thanks man, it helped. But this is so unobvious, really :c

Comment: In my opinion, *Use English function names* should be the default, and the semicolon should be the default separator.  These two things would help make LO consistent for everyone to work together.  See https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/131311/why-do-i-often-get-an-error-508-504-502-eg-if-i-paste-a-calc-formula-from-some-post-into-my-sheet/.

Comment: It appears that *entering* the formula requires the use of `;` even though it will be displayed with `,` after entering it, despite `,` being specified as the separator, with `Use English function names` selected.